# How to highlight text from paragraph using protractor?

Tags: javascript, angular, protractor, e2e-testing

I have notes section where user related data is present.  This data is dynamic.  I want to select one or two words from that notes section.
Text is seperated indexwise.  E. G.  'Any' word is having 3 indexes.  All these notes are present under one div tag.

Please suggest how to select text or word from paragraph present there?

I tried below 1.browser.actions().keyDown(protractor.Key.CTRL).sendKeys('a').perform() and

2.var Key = protractor.Key; var Key = protractor.Key; browser.actions().sendKeys(Key.chord(Key.CONTROL, 's')).perform(); browser.actions().sendKeys(Key.chord(Key.CONTROL, Key.SHIFT, 'm')).perform(); browser.actions().sendKeys(Key.chord(Key.CONTROL, 'o')).perform();

Comment: What have you tried so far? What are you currently trying? What specific issues/errors are you getting?

Comment: I tried below command browser.actions().keyDown(protractor.Key.CTRL).sendKeys('a').perform()                                                              var Key = protractor.Key;
var Key = protractor.Key;
browser.actions().sendKeys(Key.chord(Key.CONTROL, 's')).perform();
browser.actions().sendKeys(Key.chord(Key.CONTROL, Key.SHIFT, 'm')).perform();
browser.actions().sendKeys(Key.chord(Key.CONTROL, 'o')).perform();

Comment: please update your question with this information :)

Answer (score 0):

elements have a getText() function

so get the element and then getText() from it

```
async function someName(elementID){
    const elem = element(by.id(elementID));
    return await elem.getText();
}
```

you can then parse the string however you like

Comment: No static content is present.  It will always be dynamic content.  I want to select text and then want to do right click.  I think this getText method is not working

Comment: as in you want to highlight the text and then right click it?

Comment: Yes.. Text is dynamic but every letter is defined by indexes.